# Randomly shuffle columns except first column

Tags: r, random, shuffle

I want to randomly shuffle all columns in a data frame, except the 1st column. The 1st column should remain in its place.

So far I've only figured out how to shuffle *all* columns, but this includes the first column.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20),nrow=5))
df <- df[,sample(ncol(df))]
```

Here, X1 should remain in its place while X2, X3 and X4 should be shuffled randomly.

```
> df
      X1         X2         X3         X4
1  0.2582514 -0.3615941  0.5114984 -0.6918975
2  1.8234944 -0.5024039  0.9252904 -1.0034840
3  0.1513888  0.1269615 -1.2987913 -0.7017240
4 -0.8194843  1.1256620  2.0126086  1.7089314
5 -0.6733888 -1.1731604 -0.1649225 -1.7343608
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Just exclude the first one:

```
df[, c(1, sample(2:ncol(df)))]
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how your answer would change for the following question similar to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687700/how-to-randomly-shuffle-a-populaiton-by-preserving-all-properites-except-one/60687757#60687757