# How to randomly shuffle a populaiton by preserving all properites except one?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, shuffle

A spherical region of space is filled with a specific distribution of smaller, different size spheres. Each sphere is associated with some physical properties: position, radius, mass, velocity, and ID all represented as 1d or 3d `numpy` arrays. I would like to shuffle this population of spheres in a totally *random* manner such that any single sphere preserves all of its properties except its 3d position array. I have encountered this similar question in here ([Randomly shuffle columns except first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927620/randomly-shuffle-columns-except-first-column)) but, is there an easy and fast pythonic way to do this without using DataFrame?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **pandas**, you could just shuffle one column:

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].sample(frac=1).values
```

This works equally well on any subset of columns, e.g.

```py
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].sample(frac=1).values
```

The two columns are shuffled together, i.e. their respective values remain aligned.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34879805/2123555).

Comment: Thank you Kris, what if I want to shuffle two columns simultaneously meaning the corresponding values of any row remain together as we shuffle the columns?

Comment: @Ash Have a look at the updated answer. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Knuth shuffle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation), its quite straight-forward.

You can adapt the implementation algorithm to only swap your desired properties.

Comment: Thank you. That page is in C language. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with C. But, I will try to understand it.

Comment: here is the format of the column before [[ -36.12  -51.06  222.9 ]
 [-211.2    21.56  215.1 ]
 [-215.3   -36.88  175.9 ]
 ...
 [ 181.9    53.9   185.1 ]
 [ 145.1   156.4   159.  ]
 [ -16.59   11.52  165.8 ]] and here is its format after the shuffle [list([9.32, 6.92, -9.669]) list([67.61, 116.6, 35.13])
 list([149.4, 107.3, 159.8]) ... list([79.3, -44.27, 0.03649])
 list([19.0, -13.63, -16.86]) list([140.0, -177.1, 104.0])]. Can you help me fixe it in a way that I get the same format afterwards?